# How to use Box-Tidwell in R in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

For a logistic regression, I want to test the **assumption of a lineair relation between the independent variables and the log-odds** of Y.

I have read about using the **Box-Tidwell** test for this. Applying the test keeps resulting in errors, so I'm hoping to get some assistence on the code.

My dataset consists of about 80 variables. My dependent variabele is a dichotomous variable. My independent variables consist of continuous variables, as well as factors.

The **first question** I have is which **Y** to use in the box-tidwell.

I specified Y by running glm (family=binomial) on all the predictors and taking the log-odds:

```
odds = ...$fitted.values / (1-...$fitted.values)   
log_odds <- log(odds)
```

This means that the Y I use for the box-tidwell is based on the model without the x ln(x) interactions. I'm wondering if this is the right way. 
I cannot think of another way to specify the model in the Box_Tidwell.
Should I perhaps define the glm in the Box_Tidwell test, and if yes, how should I do this (i.e. which code should I use)?

The **second question** I have concerns the specification of X1 en X2.
I specified x1 in the BT by adding a fraction (0.01) to all continuous predictors (since BT cannot handle zeroes) and therefore first selecting all continuous predictors.
Since I read that X1 and X2 should be matrixes I did the following:

```
DF_numeric <- Filter(is.numeric, DF)  
x <- DF_numeric + 0.01   
x_matrix <- as.matrix (x)
```

As I understand X2 should contain variables in the model that are not candidates for transformation, so:

```
x2 <- Filter(is.factor, DF)   
x2_matrix <- as.matrix (x2)
```

I get the following error, when running my BT:

```
BT <- boxTidwell(Y=log_odds, x1=x_matrix, x2=x2_matrix)   
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(250L, 250L, 194L, 250L,  : 
replacement has 480090 rows, data has 6155
```

The 480090 rows are the 6155 participants times the number of variables, but I don't know which mistake I make.

I tried different possibilities. Since the log_odds I use for the Y are not in the same dataframe as X1 en X2 I tried binding (with cbind) x1, x2 and log_odds. This however does not change the error.

Should I use different formats for Y, X or X2?

I hope I have given enough information and hope you can help me!

(I first asked this question in Cross Validated, but since it was off-topic there, I hope this is the correct place).

Thanks in advance!
Simone